# AngularJS Resource won't work with an array

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use AngularJS to retrieve a JSON array (a list of strings).  I have created a Resource, like so:

```
packageResource.factory('Package', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/static/package.json', {}, {
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                return angular.fromJson(data)
            },
            isArray: true
        }
    });
}]);
```

And my Controller like this:

```
MainController = [
    '$scope', 'Package', function($scope, Saved, Rules) {
        $scope.package = (Package.get());
    }
];
```

And my template:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in package">{{item}}</li>
</ul>

<p> {{package}}</p>
```

I expect it to display a list of all the items in the package.json array, and then, for testing, I added the `{{package}}` and would expect it to print the contents, but instead, I get:

> - {}
> - {}
> - {}
> - {}
> - {"0":"s","1":"r","2":"d"}

The JSON file contains the following:

```
[1,3,6,"srd"]
```

However, if I change my package.json to an object, it works perfectly. For example:

```
{
  "author": "John",
  "name": "project",
  "version": 1
}
```

And of course, change `isArray` to `false`. I get:

> - John
> - project
> - 1

So it appears that something can't handle an array, and mangles it into an object. I am having trouble figuring out what - all the Angular documentation shows Resource and Scope working with arrays, and it doesn't make since for them not to. I explicitly added the `isArray: true` flag to my Resource definition, but no luck.

I am using Angular version 1.0.8.  I am a complete newbie, so it may be something painfully obvious, but I have been trying to get this to work for over a day now.

Comment: What's a list, if not an array, in JSON terms?

Comment: How, exactly, is a list different from an array?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to JavaScript and JSON- This is what I thought was an array {"name":"John","age":20} whereas a list would be [1,2,4,6]

Am I using the wrong terminology?  I am using a JSON serializer to produce my output, so I don't think I am wrong that it is valid JSON, am I?

Okay, I just Googled it- apparently I should have said object instead of array, and array instead of list.  Sorry!  I can't edit the title now though...

Comment: All right, I used my new found knowledge of json/javascript nomenclature and ran several more tests- still not able to get it to work properly, and I have updated the question with the new details with corrected terminology.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isArray=true means your json data looks like an array of objects, aka, a list. Each item in the array must be an object. so your json data needs to be [{name:value,name2:value2},{etc},{etc}].

isArray=false means your json data is a singular object.

This is the standard way of representing the restful data that $resource was designed to work with.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer- I have been looking at other frameworks and noticed a similar pattern in the way the data was represented, so I am going to re-work my code to provide the data in the more common format.